# ¿Por qué no puedo graficar con más datos?

Tags: python, array

Estoy intentando generar un ajuste de parábola por medio de mínimos cuadrados, entonces estoy tomando 30 números aleatorios y toman valores para x,y y con eso genero mis listas.

Lo que intento hacer es ajustar el polinomio de segundo grado

```
P_2(x)= a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 x^2
```

[image: polinomio]

y utilizo 30 datos aleatorios que están dentro de una región y cuando intento graficarlos me aparece la recta porque el x^2 se vuelve 0 pero cuando solo utilizo 9 datos que esten cercanos (en el rango) si se grafica.

El rango para los datos de x es de 153 a 446.
El rango para los datos de y es de 117 a 170.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.linalg as linalg


    dx= [333, 439, 266, 169, 360, 208, 384, 199, 379, 303, 392, 390, 279, 342, 430, 373, 189, 280, 218, 
    374, 366, 171, 396, 165, 328, 210, 441, 344, 216, 214]
    dy= [128, 140, 142, 131, 136, 155, 159, 117, 122, 123, 127, 126, 139, 145, 151, 143, 147, 158, 124, 
    150, 167, 161, 152, 121, 164, 119, 168, 156, 118, 170]

    xi=sorted(dx)
    yi=sorted(dy)
    x= np.array(xi)
    y=np.array(yi)

    plt.plot(x,y,'ok',label='data')

    n=len(x)
    F1=[n,sum(x),sum(x**2)]
    F2=[sum(x),sum(x**2),sum(x**3)]
    F3=[sum(x**2),sum(x**3),sum(x**4)]

    M=np.array([F1,F2,F3])
    v=np.array([sum(y),sum(x*y),sum((x**2)*y)])
    solution=linalg.solve(M,v)
    a0=solution[0]
    a1=solution[1]
    a2=solution[2]
    #print("a0= {:.3f}".format(a0),"a1= {:.3f}".format(a1),"a2= {:.3f}".format(a2))

    x_curve=np.linspace(0,5,100)
    y_curve=a0+a1*x_curve+a2*(x_curve**2)
    plt.plot(x_curve,y_curve,'b--',label='Mejor parabola')
    plt.legend()
```

Comment: Perdona, pero No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Por un lado, tienes la expresión matemática que es una parábola, luego tienes un conjunto de datos, que representan una recta. Después cuando creas ```M``` y ```v```  tienes que ```linalg.solver()``` espera una matriz cuadrada de rango igual al número de betas (en tu caso 3), pero tu le pasas `M`  que no es una matriz como la anterior que he descrito. Yo lo que haría sería entender bien el problema que quieres resolver matemáticamente, y después buscar las herramientas que se adaptan a tu problema para resolverlo.

Comment: Quiero hacer un ajuste de parábola por medio de minimos cuadrados, eso es lo que intento hacer. (Es la primera vez que lo hago así que creo que es por eso que me marca tantos errores).

Comment: El error es por el tipo que le pasas a algún método. Ayudaría saber la línea que te falla. Le estás pasando un array a algo que no espera recibir un array y de ahí el fallo

Comment: Considero que el error es más bien que no gráfica los datos, ya edité la pregunta. Una disculpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as linalg


dx= [333, 439, 266, 169, 360, 208, 384, 199, 379, 303, 392, 390, 279, 342, 430, 373, 
189, 280, 218, 374, 366, 171, 396, 165, 328, 210, 441, 344, 216, 214]
dy= [128, 140, 142, 131, 136, 155, 159, 117, 122, 123, 127, 126, 139, 145, 151, 143, 
147, 158, 124, 150, 167, 161, 152, 121, 164, 119, 168, 156, 118, 170]

xi=sorted(dx)
yi=sorted(dy)
x= np.array(xi,dtype='int64')
y= np.array(yi,dtype='int64')

plt.plot(x,y,'ok',label='data')

n=len(x)
F1=[n,sum(x),sum(x**2)]
F2=[sum(x),sum(x**2),sum(x**3)]
F3=[sum(x**2),sum(x**3),sum(x**4)]

M=np.array([F1,F2,F3])
v=np.array([sum(y),sum(x*y),sum((x**2)*y)])
solution=linalg.solve(M,v)
a0=solution[0]
a1=solution[1]
a2=solution[2]
print("a0= {:.3f}".format(a0),"a1= {:.3f}".format(a1),"a2= {:.3f}".format(a2))

x_curve=x
y_curve=a0+a1*x_curve+a2*(x_curve**2)
plt.plot(x_curve,y_curve,'b--',label='Mejor parabola')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema creo es que el dominio de tu data y la parábola ajustada son distintos, ajustas el dato pero intentas obervar la parábola ajustada en un dominio distinto. Creo que lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as linalg


dx= [333, 439, 266, 169, 360, 208, 384, 199, 379, 303, 392, 390, 279, 342, 430, 373, 189, 280, 218, 
374, 366, 171, 396, 165, 328, 210, 441, 344, 216, 214]
dy= [128, 140, 142, 131, 136, 155, 159, 117, 122, 123, 127, 126, 139, 145, 151, 143, 147, 158, 124, 
150, 167, 161, 152, 121, 164, 119, 168, 156, 118, 170]

xi=sorted(dx)
yi=sorted(dy)
x= np.array(xi)
y=np.array(yi)

plt.plot(x,y,'ok',label='data')

n=len(x)
F1=[n,sum(x),sum(x**2)]
F2=[sum(x),sum(x**2),sum(x**3)]
F3=[sum(x**2),sum(x**3),sum(x**4)]

M=np.array([F1,F2,F3])
v=np.array([sum(y),sum(x*y),sum((x**2)*y)])
solution=linalg.solve(M,v)
a0=solution[0]
a1=solution[1]
a2=solution[2]
#print("a0= {:.3f}".format(a0),"a1= {:.3f}".format(a1),"a2= {:.3f}".format(a2))

x_curve=x
y_curve=a0+a1*x_curve+a2*(x_curve**2)
plt.plot(x_curve,y_curve,'b--',label='Mejor parabola')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Quiero que me aparezca esa pequeña corvatura como la que te aparece a ti en la gráfica que muestras, estoy intentando con el código que me compartiste pero la "curva de mejor parábola" me aparece una recta apesar de que tengo exactamente el mismo código que tu. ¿Cómo puedo obtener esa corvatura de tu gráfica?

Comment: ¿ Has copiado exactamente mi código ? Ten cuidado que el cambio es muy sutil. Si no te funciona y has copiado el mismo código solo puedo pensar que tienen alguna variable apuntando al lugar equivocado. Levanta un nuevo jupyter notebook , copia y pega ( es solo una idea, no la solución...)

Comment: He copiado exactamente el mismo código, realmente no entiendo porque a ti si te aparece. Des-comenté la línea donde se imprimen los valores a0= 85.118         
a1= 0.186    a2= -0.000 y como a2  me es iguala cero, entonces considero que es por eso que me da la recta pero no entiendo por qué a ti si te aparece la corvatura.

Comment: Mis parametros son: a0= 104.436 a1= 0.044 a2= 0.000, intenta ajustar con los mismos y visualizar.

Comment: Disculpa Marmurar, me da esta alerta ¿crees que tenga que ver algo con que por eso no me dan los parámetros bien? C:\Users\DELL\Solucion.py:27: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars
  F3=[sum(x**2),sum(x**3),sum(x**4)]