# ¿Por qué no se ajusta bien la parábola (regresión cuadrática)? Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando generar una curvatura perfecta dentro del área negra que esta dentro de la boca pero cada que actualizo (que vuelvo a correr el código) algunas veces me aparece con corvatura, en otras ocasiones como si fuera una línea recta y realmente no entiendo porque esta sucediendo eso. Se supone que debe de hacer un ajuste y quedar una parábola cada que actualizo pero no funciona.

[image]

Adjunto imagen para que se tenga más claro el problema, la linea roja es la que se supone que esta haciendo el ajuste de la parábola y las cruces dentro son los puntos aleatorios que estoy tomando.

Código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
#from random import choices 
import scipy.linalg as linalg
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX



image = cv2.imread('radio3.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(image,(600,300))

hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

b=sum(hist)
objetivo = b/2
suma=0
numero=0
final=0

 for i in hist:
    suma=suma+i
    numero=numero+len(i)
    final=numero+1
    #print('Final:',final)
    if suma > objetivo: 
        break
   
U=final-3
ResFinal=U*2
y=((30*ResFinal)/100)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,y,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


#Para encontrar el área, teniendo 3000 solo queda el contorno del centro.
lista = []
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 3000 and area <  10000:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #print('El área es:',area)
        lista.append(area)
        resultado = sorted(lista, reverse=True)[0:-1]
        #print("Áreas encontradas:", resultado)
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        #Puntos para la parábola
        #Coordenadas de pixeles
        vlxU=x #+10
        vlxL=x+w
        vlyU=y #+20
        vlyL=y+h #-21  #21
        pnx=list(range(vlxU,vlxL))
        pny=list(range(vlyU,vlyL))
        #Donde tomas los 30 valores
        lx= random.choices(pnx, k=30)
        ly= random.choices(pny, k=30)
        #xi=sorted(lx)
        print('Datos de x:',lx)
        #yi=sorted(ly)
        print('Datos de y:',ly)
        #Arreglo para x y para y
        dx= np.array(lx,dtype='int64')
        dy= np.array(ly,dtype='int64')
        #Se grafican los puntos
        plt.plot(dx,dy,'+w')
        
        #Para hacer la parábola
        n=len(dx)
        F1=[n,sum(dx),sum(dx**2)]
        F2=[sum(dx),sum(dx**2),sum(dx**3)]
        F3=[sum(dx**2),sum(dx**3),sum(dx**4)]
        M=np.array([F1,F2,F3])
        v=np.array([sum(dy),sum(dx*dy),sum((dx**2)*dy)])
        solution=linalg.solve(M,v)
        a0=solution[0]
        a1=solution[1]
        a2=solution[2]
        #print("a0= {:.3f}".format(a0),"a1= {:.3f}".format(a1),"a2= {:.3f}".format(a2))
        x_curve=dx
        y_curve=a0+a1*x_curve+a2*(x_curve**2)
        plt.plot(x_curve,y_curve,'r')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.legend()
        plt.imshow(th1,cmap = 'gray')
        plt.title("Funciona")
        plt.figure()
        
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya estaba realizada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué no puedo graficar con más datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399876/por-qu%c3%a9-no-puedo-graficar-con-m%c3%a1s-datos)

Comment: ¿Por qué creastes un nuevo usuario?

Comment: No recuerdo mi otra cuenta :(